# Spring Boot 2.0 Not Registering Custom Actuator Endpoint Bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to add a custom actuator endpoint in Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE application.
I'm following [the official guidelines](https://spring.io/blog/2017/08/22/introducing-actuator-endpoints-in-spring-boot-2-0), [the official migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Migrating-a-custom-Actuator-endpoint-to-Spring-Boot-2) and also [this post](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators).

I am able to configure everything via properties: hide/expose endpoints, change base path etc. Everything works, except my custom endpoint bean is not picked up by `WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping`. It simply doesn't show up in these famous logging lines:

```
EndpointLinksResolver        : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
```

These three lines is all I get. I can access `/actuator/health` and `/actuator/info` without any trouble, but not my custom endpoint. I get 404 obviously.

What I tried so far:

- Checked that my endpoint class is registered in the context as a bean.
- Exposed it explicitly via yaml configuration.
- Exposed everything via `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`
- Removed all the management configuration completely, because it should be actually available by default.
- Triple checked the endpoint id.
- Renamed the endpoint id.

Any ideas of what I can at least look into? All the questions I found so far end up in person not realizing they need `@Component` annotation too.

Ah, here is my class by the way:

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "hello")
public class HelloEndpoint {

    @ReadOperation
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sanity check: component scan on?

Comment: Yeah, checked it. See the answer by me below. I'm actually just stupid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After posting the question I found the answer almost immediately. It was a combination of typos in the config and the fact that it's actually **not exposed by default**. Despite [the official post saying](https://spring.io/blog/2017/08/22/introducing-actuator-endpoints-in-spring-boot-2-0#configuration):

> To configure an endpoint, all that’s required really is to expose it as a @Bean

These are the proper ways to define the property:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include='health,info,metrics,hello'
```

Or as a YAML:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: 'health,info,metrics,hello'
```

Here is the official reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints

Interesting, that you can't use underscores in endpoint names anymore. At least without additional changes.